# Change VSCode User Settings location

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to put my User Settings file under version control, preferably a separate folder, but I can't find the option to tell VSCode where my settings file is located.

Is there a way to change the location that Visual Studio Code looks for the `settings.json` file?

**Update:**

Since there does not seem to be a easy way to change the default location of the user settings file, besides passing the command line arguments as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575963/4050456) answer, I went with a different approach.

I created a git repository which contains all of my dotfiles, settings-files, etc. and put my `settings.json` there. This repository is cloned somewhere on the development partition of my hard drive. I then created a Symlink using the `mklink.exe` tool (I am on Windows) to the settings file in my repository in the default user settings directory (`path-to-user/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/` on Windows). The only drawback is that you can't move the repository, or change its layout without having to recreate the link.

Changing the Symlink to a Hardlink is not advised as explained in [this](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/git-dotfiles-and-hardlinks/) blog-post. Also Hardlinks seem to mess up the timestamps on Windows, so you won't see any changes made to `settings.json` from within VSCode. The Symlink seems to be working tho.

Comment: Hi! Just to clarify: did you create a symlink from your dotfiles folder to VSCode's default location or viceversa?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the location of the global user data folder by launching from the command line with the `--user-data-dir` option. But I just initialized a git repo in the default user settings location and keep it in source control there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also thought about initializing the git repository in the user settings location, but this prohibits me from using a universal dotfiles repository where i can also manage other settings files. See my question update for my current solution!

Comment: All [Command line options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line).

Comment: If you do `code --user-data-dir <user>`, a folder will be created with your `<user`, so pay attention as you probably do not want it.

Answer (score 10):

You can add a settings file for a workspace like this :

```
/yourproject/.vscode/settings.json
```

Or use the editor and goto :`Preferences->settings` and select workspace settings in the top bar.

These can be checked into your project and then to source control.

Reference : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings

The file is created for you by default when editing the settings in your workspace. There you can select User or Workspace settings.

> You can also open the Settings editor from the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) with Preferences: Open Settings or use the keyboard shortcut (⌘,).

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a way to change the global user settings location, but if this is the way to go that's fine for me too. Thank you very much!

Comment: then you'd have to change the global users settings location on each system.

Comment: This was what i was opting for, since i use vscode for so many one-off edits that i like having the global configuration for the editor and the file types i usually edit.

Comment: @corn3lius What do you base your answer on? I haven't found any documentation that specifies `settings.json` can be in any other place other than the default one in `%APPDATA%`. I even tried placing it into `.vscode`, however, it didn't work: settings were not applied.

Comment: @Danijel : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_creating-user-and-workspace-settings This describes the difference between user and workspace settings.

Comment: It does not say anything about settings.json alternative location(s).

Comment: @Danijel the editor creates the file in your project when you edit it. The guide tells you how to edit it. The files location is explained in the editor.

Comment: @Danijel https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations
_The workspace setting file is located under the .vscode folder in your root folder._ please read the documentation.

Comment: That's workspace settings file, I asked about user `settings.json`: "what do you base your answer on? I haven't found any documentation that specifies `settings.json` can be in any other place other than the default one." So, where did you get the info about placing `settings.json` into `.vscode`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable), there is a "portable mode" that can be enabled precisely to enable *all* the user data to be in one place:

> Visual Studio Code supports Portable mode. This mode enables all data created and maintained by VS Code to live near itself, so it can be moved around across environments.
>
> This mode also provides a way to set the installation folder location for VS Code extensions, useful for corporate environments that prevent extensions from being installed in the Windows AppData folder.
>
> Portable mode is supported on the ZIP download for Windows, and the TAR.GZ download for Linux, as well as the regular Application download for macOS. See the Download page to find the correct .zip / .tar.gz file for your platform.

And [here is how you do it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable#_enable-portable-mode):

> ### Windows, Linux
>
> After unzipping the VS Code download, create a data folder within VS Code's folder:
>
> ```
> |- VSCode-win32-x64-1.25.0-insider
> |   |- Code.exe (or code executable)
> |   |- data
> |   |- ...
> ```
>
> From then on, that folder will be used to contain all VS Code data, including session state, preferences, extensions, etc.
>
> The data folder can be moved to other VS Code installations. This is useful for updating your portable VS Code version, in which case you can move the data folder to a newer extracted version of VS Code.

Now you can put the `data` directory anywhere you want ... with the help of a symlink.  (The `scoop` package manager on Windows uses a junction point.)

*n.b.*: On my system the contents of this folder is about 2+Gb after ~6mo of moderate use.  I sure as hell don't know everything that's in there - and I also don't know how to clean things up (there are a lot of directories named `*cache*` among lots of other stuff).  So I'm pretty sure you *don't* want to just place the whole damn thing under source control.  But once you have the location of it *fixed* you can easily find your settings file in `./user-data/User` along with your (user) keybindings and your snippets, and you can put *those* in source control however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Another good option (if you'll pardon the late response) for versioning VSCode's user settings would be to use the Git "bare" repo method of versioning dot-files, as outlined here:

https://www.ackama.com/blog/posts/the-best-way-to-store-your-dotfiles-a-bare-git-repository-explained

By making $HOME your Git working directory for a Git Bare repo, all files under $HOME are eligible to be Git-Tracked, including VSCode's user settings. What I like about this approach is it works without moving dot-files or VSCode settings away from their default or expected paths.

Comment: linked url has gone..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change the Visual Studio Code settings as much as possible.

```bash
HOME=/path/to/alternative/user/home code --user-data-dir /path/to/alternative/user-data-dir
```