# can't add workspace in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just started with Visual Studio Code. I need to add more workspaces after the original one.

I tried googling the docs but there is no reference.

How do I add more workspaces?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a 'workspace' in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629890/what-is-a-workspace-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 1):

As AitlioA said, in the same workspace is not possible.

If you want to create more workspaces:

- Add folder in the same window: File > Add Folder to Workspace
- Repeat many time as you want.
- Save your workspace: File > Save Workspace As...

It will save your workspaces including all your folders. Next time, just select

- File > Open workspace

Check the documentation: [Multi root workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open multiple workspaces in the same window? This isn't possible.
See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43188).