# How do I set my workspace folder in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

**How do I set my workspace folder in Visual Studio Code?**

This appears to be necessary for debugging, and I suspect it's why my breakpoints aren't getting hit.

Further reading:

1. This [question about adding workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53144444/cant-add-workspace-in-visual-studio-code) doesn't have an accepted answer.
2. [What is a 'workspace' in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629890/what-is-a-workspace-in-vs-code), while providing a wealth of information, does not explain how to set a workspace for debugging.
3. [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings). The documentation also does not mention how to set a workspace for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **How do I set my workspace folder in Visual Studio Code?**

1. Open Visual Studio Code. You should be on the Welcome page.
2. Add workspace folder...

[image: Add workspace folder link]

3. File explorer opens. Select the folder you want for your workspace. Add.

Now your workspace folder is shown in the left pane :-)

[image: workspace folder]

Comment: Can we launch a workspace from the command line? e.g. `code ./hello-world.code-workspace`

Comment: After reviewing the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/) > User Guide > Command Line and Multi-Root Workspaces, I found nothing. Maybe there is a round-about way...

Comment: If there are more than one workspace folder, does it take the first one? I think I have to move the folder I want to the iop.

Answer (score 1):

Create a launch.json and set your workspace in "**cwd**"

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "*your/new/workspace/*",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```