# Is it possible to install and enable workspace extensions in VSCode with the .vscode folder?

Tags: ide, visual-studio-code

What I want to achieve:

1. I want my projects to be self-contained in a manner that will allow collaborators to start working on them with all the proper linting and language features etc.. *(I know this is a bit harsh in the sense that i am "forcing" an IDE in it, but for the sake of the problem it is helpful.)*
2. I want my projects to be self-contained so that i have full config control over which extensions work and which don't when i approach working on them. I don't want to be dependant on my own machine with my own vscode user config. I don't want to be dependent on extension I have installed in the past. And i also don't want different extension to be mixed up. I want everything disabled on the global user space and only enabled in controlled manned via some in project setting file.

**What I think I basically need:**

A "VSCode extension manager" that can work locally in the dir. Sort of like an `npm` for vscode.

So i would be able to structure extension "dependencies" and run an install and locally enable the extension to work on the specific workspace.

`extension.package`

```json
{
  "extensions": {
    "eslint": "6.4^"
    "babel": "15.2^"
  }
}
```

Then there would be the regular configuration files for these extension available already with the git - and if not perhaps they can be auto-generated with some default settings.

and all the developer would need to do is run some bash code command.

---

**Does something like this exist? Is such a functionality available to achieve?**

Answer (score 19):

The only thing that I have found so far that is at least a bit of help is to have recommended extensions for a workspace :S
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions

> You can create a recommended list of extensions for a workspace with the Extensions: Configure Recommended Extensions (Workspace) command.
>   [...]
>
> An example extensions.json could be:
>
> ```
>    {
>      "recommendations": [
>        "ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin",
>        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
>        "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome"
>      ]
>    }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

There is a portable version of Visual Studio Code: [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable)

Edit:

From the doc: "Visual Studio Code supports Portable mode. This mode enables all data created and maintained by VS Code to live near itself, so it can be moved around across environments.". That means you can have a version of vscode per project with all the data (extensions, preferences, etc...) stored in the same place (i.e. in the project root folder). It's a bit heavy for what you want to do but it should work.

Comment: This is not what is being asked. The question is related to "I want extensions X,Y,Z to be launched when I am in this Project 1, and extensions A,B,C to be launched when I am in Project 2". The answer is _not_ portable vscode, as in either of the above instances, the user is still working within the same machine and file system.

Comment: From the doc: "Visual Studio Code supports Portable mode. This mode enables all data created and maintained by VS Code to live near itself, so it can be moved around across environments.". That means you can have a version of vscode per project with all the data (extensions, preferences, etc...) stored in the same place (i.e. in the project root folder). That answers the question.