# Download extension only for current project

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I download an extension in VS Code and make sure that it doesn't apply across the current profile?

Use case: I have a Python profile, and I've set it up to usually no install Jupyter extensions. However, I need them for one project. So how can I install the Jupyter extensions to just this one workspace?

Comment: VSCode extensions are enabled globally and you can disable one for current workspace. That's exactly the opposite of what you want to do. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529463/is-it-possible-to-install-and-enable-workspace-extensions-in-vscode-with-the-vs

Comment: disable global and enable per workspace