# Where does VSCode store the enabled/disabled state for extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've got some extensions installed that are only enabled in a specific workspace.

With settings, normally workspace specific stuff is saved in .vscode/settings.json within the workspace folder. However, this doesn't seem to be the case for extensions.

I know extensions themselves are installed in .vscode/extensions within the user profile folder, but I can't find anything that dictates whether or not they're enabled or disabled. This is true for locally, remotely, and in a given workspace.

Checking through settings sync seems to show an extensions.json that lists all installed extensions with their enabled/disabled state, but I can't find this file locally anywhere in either my workspace, my remote, or locally.

Where is this configuration file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a quick test it appears that extension states are stored in `state.vscdb` sqlite databases under `extensionsIdentifiers/disabled` key

Global:

```
<vsc user profile folder>/user-data/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb
```

Workspace-specific:

```
<vsc user profile folder>/user-data/User/workspaceStorage/<workspace ID>/state.vscdb
```

For context, the global `settings.json` file location is

```
<vsc user profile folder>/user-data/User/settings.json
```

and really does not seem to store extensions list nor state; just their preferences.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting that they're not also stored as json files, but explains why I was having no luck trying to find them.

Comment: how can we get the workspace id from the workspace folder?

Answer (score 1):

A [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58905720/1757756) by [@gino-mempin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2745495/gino-mempin) described how to query the SQLite tables in the `state.vscdb` files that contain the extension states using the [SQLite browser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/). To query the `vscdb` programmatically using PowerShell, [please see another SO answer here about querying for cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66272141/1757756).

Recall that [the global `settings.json` file location](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations) by operating system is

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json` or `$env:APPDATA\Code\User\settings.json`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

I use an asterisk `*` after `Code` to account for possible the `Code - Insiders` construction of the Insiders build, if you're on the [Insiders channel](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/). For global settings, relative to `settings.json`, `state.vscdb` is located in `./User/globalStorage/state.vscdb`.

```pwsh
Resolve-Path "$env:APPDATA\Code*\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb"  # global settings store for extensions
```

For workspace specific settings, again relative to the `settings.json`, `state.vscdb` per workspace is stored in `./User/workspaceStorage/<ExtensionContext.storageUri>/state.vscdb`

Again, for example, PowerShell in Windows:

```pwsh
Resolve-Path "$env:APPDATA\Code*\User\workspaceStorage\*\state.vscdb"  # workspace settings store for extensions
```

The `ExtensionContext.storageUri` refers to the uri of a workspace specific directory in which the extension can store private state. This can be found using [the Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) (Help > Toggle Developer Tools)

[image: Toggle Developer Tools in the Help menu]

Then, in the console, type

```js
let config = await vscode.context.resolveConfiguration();
config.workspace;
```

Here is a screen recording of this process:

[image: Getting the workspace ID from VS Code Developer Tools]

See [the VS Code API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext.storageUri) for more information on the `ExtensionContext.storageUri` within the context of extension development.