# VSCODE: how remove bad character checker for .tmpl files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just upgraded vscode to 1.63.2, and got this error. How to disable the checker for `.tmpl` files

[image]

Comment: Could this be answered by this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562455/visual-studio-code-disabling-error-warning-checks-in-for-specific-file-type

Comment: Which language is it - it looks like different languages might use the `.tmpl` extension?

Comment: @Mark, we have some custom template for server configuration, so need to use [ and ]

then the latest vscode just detect it as error, i just want to turn off that checker