# How to rename a workspace in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My vscode project has an "app" folder which is the root folder for my workspace.

It is possible to change the title of this workspace?

[image: workspaces]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use the "File -> Save Workspace As ..." to save it into a file.

[image: Menu]

Normally, you would only want to use a `<name>.code-workspace` file with multi-root projects (that is, projects that include multiple folders), but this is also the only way to rename a workspace.

More information:

- [What is a workspace in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629890/what-is-a-workspace-in-visual-studio-code)
- [Saving workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-file)

P.S. All the credit goes to [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9547389/henry) for pointing me to `.code-workspace` files :) Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't really rename the workspace, it just duplicates the workspace file under a new name. So, you still have the old workspace file that you'll then have to delete manually.

Answer (score 19):

Simply edit the .code-workspace file contained in the actual folder (via file explorer) and rename it. That's it!

Comment: You should probably go to **File --> Close Workspace** first, and _then_ use your file explorer to rename the workspace file, and then re-open the workspace.

Comment: @GabrielStaples If you save the .code-workspace file, the Visual Studio Code UI updates pretty much immediately, even if it's open. I think it's designed such that there's no need to close the workspace first.

Answer (score 17):

I haven't yet found a way to change the name of the workspace itself (without changing the filename); but one thing not mentioned in other answers that might be relevant:  you can edit the .code-workspace file and add a `name` property to set a custom display name for each folder in your workspace:

```json
{   
  "folders": [
    {
      "path": "../path/to/folder",
      "name": "my custom folder name"
    }
  ],
  "settings": {}
}
```

Comment: reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_workspace-file-schema

Answer (score 13):

Another setting I always use, is to change the text in the title bar `"window.title"` (aside from changing colors per workspace). This helps me distinguish different workspace easily.

`.code-workspace` file (`Ctrl+Shift+P` (Or `F1`) option `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`

```
{
"folders": [
    {
        "path": "./path/to/workspace",
        "name": "My custom name"
    }
],
"settings": {
    "window.title": "My custom title",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "titleBar.activeBackground": "#DBEAFE",
        "titleBar.activeForeground": "#000000",
        "activityBar.activeBackground": "#DBEAFE",
        "activityBar.activeBorder": "#000099",
        "activityBar.background": "#DBEAFE",
        "activityBar.foreground": "#000099",
        "activityBar.inactiveForeground": "#686575",
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#000099",
        "activityBarBadge.foreground": "#FFFFFF",
        "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#FEAC32"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this `workspace.json` ? How do you access this file? I was able to access it via Ctrl+Shift+P > `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`. This worked well for a multi-root workspace.

Comment: @qyb2zm302 Yes, indeed, via `Ctrl+Shift+P` (Or `F1`) option `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings (JSON)`. Another way is to open the `.code-workspace` file from the filesystem using a text editor.

Comment: This works only if you open the workspace as a folder. When opened as a _workspace_ `window.title` is ignored (greyed out; hovering it will explain why).

Comment: @Kamafeather : Not sure what you mean, the `code.workspace` file only exists if it is a workspace. I always open workspaces.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, VSCode can open folders "as folder" even when there's a `workspace` file. It will prompt to re-open "as workspace" using that file, but it's not automatic. Some settings are considered only when opened "as folder" while others considered only when opened "as workspace". – But, as I said, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

### How to rename a VSCode workspace:

1. <kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>Close Workspace</kbd>.

   [image]
2. Manually rename the workspace file in your operating system's file explorer or terminal. Ex: on Linux or Mac or in the git bash terminal using Git For Windows:

   ```sh
   cd path/to/workspace
   mv old_workspace_name.code-workspace new_workspace_name.code-workspace
   ```
3. <kbd>File</kbd> --> <kbd>Open Workspace from File...</kbd>, then select the workspace you just renamed.

   [image]

### See Also:

1. The other answers here.
2. Official VSCode documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_save-workspace-as