# visual studio delete project from workspace and create index

Tags: macos, visual-studio, workspace

[when I add my folder in visual studio workspace, it create me new file(index.code-workspace)and when I delete it then my folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUFuV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read these posts: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a 'workspace' in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629890/what-is-a-workspace-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a workspace in Visual Studio Code Editor creates a JSON file named `*.code-workspace`. This JSON file is used to automatically restore all workspace settings in case you create a multi-root workspace.

###### References

- [What is a 'workspace' in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629890/what-is-a-workspace-in-visual-studio-code)
- [What is a VS Code "workspace"?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces)

Comment: uh... ok... thx ! can i delete this and it has a big impact on my project?

Comment: I think it is necessary for you to stay here for a while to learn the flow, to learn the developments that will happen.

Comment: After expressing your problem more clearly, you need to share your problem by warning certain patterns. If the answer to the question you shared is available in another post, users will mark your question as duplicate. I recommend following this pattern when creating a post: `1` tools used, programming method and other general information. `2` your intended target point in the project. `3` sample codes. `4` explaining, reporting the error and expressing the request for help. `5` screenshots of the problem.